# problems with struts 2 developing login

Tags: struts2

I have several problems and I would if someone can help me to solve this with Struts 2. This is the problem I have. When I run my simple Login Application I have this mistake:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.

This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]

The log is this one:

```
Advertencia: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.TagUtils.getStack(TagUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.StrutsBodyTagSupport.getStack(StrutsBodyTagSupport.java:44)
    at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:48)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspx_meth_s_form_0(Login_jsp.java:99)
    at org.apache.jsp.Login_jsp._jspService(Login_jsp.java:72)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The file tree is this one:

```
            src(es.uniway.action.login as a package and inside this class:
LoginAction.java:

package com.uniway.action.login;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{

@Override
public String execute() throws Exception {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return SUCCESS;
}

}
```

As well inside of the src I have the struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
 "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>

<constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

<action name="Login" class="com.uniway.action.LoginAction">
<result name="input">/Login.jsp</result>
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">/index.jsp</result>
</action>


</package>


<!-- Add packages here -->

</struts>
```

Then at web-info folder I have the `web.xml` which I have this thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_9" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>cloud46</display-name>
<filter>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


 <welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>Login.jsp</welcome-file>

 </welcome-file-list>
 </web-app>
```

And after that at WebContent I have index.jsp and Login.jsp which I have this code:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sign On</title>
</head>

<body>
<s:form action="Login.action"> 
<s:textfield key="username"/>
<s:password key="password" />
<s:submit method="execute"/>
</s:form>  
</body>
</html>
```

And the libraries at the lib folder inside of the WEB-INF are : `asm-3.3.jar`, `asm-commons-3.3.jar`, `asm-tree-3.3.jar`, `commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar`, `commons-io-2.0.1.jar`, `commons-lang3-3.1.jar`, `freemarker-2.3.19.jar`, `javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar`, `ognl-3.0.5.jar`
, `struts2-core-2.3.3.jar`, `xwork-core-2.3.3.jar` . Please, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you access a jsp page directly, it must not have S2 tags in it--the tags expect S2-specific functionality not present in a request not handled by S2.

Comment: @Dave Newton the `<s:text>` tag will still work, though!

Comment: @rees It must do something explicit if there isn't a text provider on the stack, then.

Answer (score 1):

Do this
Change

```
<action name="Login" class="com.uniway.action.LoginAction">
<result name="input">/Login.jsp</result>
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">/index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

To

```
<action name="Login" class="com.uniway.action.LoginAction">
     <result name="input">/Login.jsp</result>
     <result name="success">/Login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

1. Change this

   `<s:form action="Login.action">` 
   To

   `<s:form namespace="/" action="Login">`
2. Next
   Change

   `<s:submit method="execute"/>`

To

```
<s:submit value="Login"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much but it doesn`t work :(, why?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with my 404.jsp page and this was my solution:

We should not use `<s:` tags in 404.jsp!!!

I don't know why, but this solved my problem!